# Give a $3$-state DFA for $(01 \cup 1)^∗$

Tags: finite-automata

[image]

How do I change the design to accept the given language, because I think my DFA can accept $001$ as well. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct that your DFA accepts 001, which is wrong.

Here is a strong hint. The three sets of strings accepted by the states should be the set of accepted strings, the set of accepted strings with one "0" attached at the end, the set of the strings that contains two consecutive "0"s. (From that description, you can see how to construct simple DFA by the Myhill–Nerode relation.)

In case the above hint does not ring a bell, here is the full answer, which you can reveal by hovering your mouse over it.

> Let state $S_1$ be the set of all strings having no consecutive "0"s and ending in "1". Let state $S_0$ be the set of all strings having no consecutive "0"s and ending in "0". Let state $S_{00}$ be the set of all strings having two consecutive "0"s. $S_1$ is the start state and the accepted state. Here are the transitions.
>
>  $\quad(S_1, 0)\mapsto S_0$
>  $\quad(S_1, 1)\mapsto S_1$
>  $\quad(S_0, 0)\mapsto S_{00}$
>  $\quad(S_0, 1)\mapsto S_1$
>  $\quad(S_{00}, 0)\mapsto S_{00}$
>  $\quad(S_{00}, 1)\mapsto S_{00}$ 
>
>
>  It should be easy to see that the above DFA accepts the given set of strings, $(01\cup 1)^*$.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get what you mean, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Suppose we have $D$, the wanted DFA. For a state $s$ in $D$, a string $w$ is said to be accepted by $s$ if given $w$ as the input, $D$ will be transitioned to $s$. Then each string will be accepted by exactly one state since $D$ is deterministic. Each state accepts a different set of strings. It is not hard to figure out what are those three sets of strings once you have read the regular expression $(01\cup1)^∗$ carefully. In fact, there are procedures how to obtain the minimal sets of strings or the minimal sets of states, which you will, I believe, learn in the later part of your course.

Answer (score 0):

Remark that at the very minimum what you need in your situation is: two transitions to discriminate 01 (this will take two states) and a third state to use as the pit (to discard words like 00).

Consider the state A, B, C. in which A is both initial and final state.
C is the pit.

Transitions:

(A,0) -> B

(A,1) -> A

(B,1) -> A

(B,0) -> C

(C,0) -> C

(C,1) -> C

Answer (score 0):

Here are the equivalence classes of the Myhill–Nerode relation:

- All strings not containing $00$ and not ending with $0$.
- All strings not containing $00$ and ending with $0$.
- All strings containing $00$.

The equivalence classes correspond to the states in the minimal DFA. In other words, these are your three states. When in the first state and reading a 0, you naturally move to the second state (since you're still avoiding 00, but now end with a 0), and when in that state and reading a 0, you naturally move to the third state (since you now contain 00). In a similar manner you can complete the description of the DFA.